# ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 400, 50)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I keep on getting this error related to the input shape. Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

```
def deep_model():

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=50, kernel_size=9, strides=1, padding='same', 
               batch_input_shape=(None, Length, 4), activation='relu'))

    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size =(9, 9), strides =(1, 1),
                    activation ='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2), strides =(2, 2)))
    model.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (9, 9), activation ='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size =(2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(100, activation ='relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.3))
    model.add(Dense(3, activation ='softmax'))

    # training the model
    model.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
                optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.01),
                metrics =['accuracy'])

    return model

x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 400, 4)
```

> raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +
> ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: :
> expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 400,
> 50)

I tried to reshape the x_train also but got this error:

> x_train = x_train.reshape(-1, 400, 400, 4) ValueError: cannot reshape
> array of size 43200000 into shape (400,400,4)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the input shape to have an extra dimension.
The reason your reshaping failed is because `400 * 400 * 4` is equal to `640000` and not `43200000`

This is how you would do it:

```py
x_train = x_train[np.newaxis]
```

Comment: Hello Vedant, Thanks for your help. I am still getting this error.    raise ValueError('Input ' + str(input_index) + ' of layer ' +
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv2d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 400, 50).